# c++ file in a gazebo model plugin?

Tags: c++, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hey all!

I'm a new ros-gazebo user, I've read some tutos and I have a question.

Is it possible to use a cpp file in a gazebo plugin model? For example, can I put the cpp file somewhere in this template explained in the [tuto](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=plugins_model&cat=write_plugin) ?
Because I have a cpp file with a main function (and some more functions) , and I have a gazebo model (an iRobot create). Is it possible for the model to follow the code (passing by the plugin, or directly, or another method)?

I guess the last solution is to convert all the cpp code in a plugin langage but is there an easier way?

Thanks in advance and have a great day.

Axxeel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16095/c++-file-in-a-gazebo-model-plugin?/) by [Axxeel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3223/axxeel/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-05-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

All gazebo plugins are in C++; there is no plugin language. Any file can be included as long as you make sure the file is in your include path. In your CMakeLists.txt this is done using `include_directories`. In the case of source files you'll have to make sure all are listed in the call to `add_library`.

You won't be able to call or run your main function. `main` as a symbol is already defined by the gazebo executable. You should treat the `Load()` method on the plugin as the entry point.

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1290/sloretz/) with karma: 558 on 2017-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1